# Run equation in every cell in a column

Tags: vba, if-statement, excel, excel-formula, calculated-columns

I am trying to run an equation in my spread sheet that will go through column "I" and delete every row that does not  have an expiration date within 90 days from now... In other words i am trying to format my spread sheet to just give me a list of everything that is expiring in the next 90 days.  The row where I put the stars is where I am having difficulty inserting the equation.  I am not sure how to insert the equation but if it was ran in cell by itself it would look like this  =IF(AND(I11-900),1,0)=1.  What would I change Q11 to be so that way when the equation is run it will apply to every cell in the I column instead of just I 11

```
Sub DeleteNow()


Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long


With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With Sheets("Copy")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "I")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                If ******************** Then .EntireRow.Delete

            End If

        End With

    Next Lrow


End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub deleteRowsWithDateNotIn90Days()
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim ctr As Integer

Dim currentCell As Range
Dim valueOfIColumn
Dim isWithin90Days As Boolean

lastRow = 17
firstRow = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Copy")
    For ctr = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
        Set currentCell = .Cells(ctr, 9)
        valueOfIColumn = currentCell.Value
        isWithin90Days = valueOfIColumn >= Date And valueOfIColumn <= (Date + 90)

        If Not isWithin90Days Then
            Debug.Print "deleting row of cell " + currentCell.Address
            currentCell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT: Use this as a basis to get started.
You can remove unnecessary code generated by the macro recorder.

Comment: How do you designate a certain column to run this equation in

Comment: In the code above, the column I which is 9th column. I have removed the need of having a formula. The check whether a date is within 90 days in done in the code above.

Comment: So if I wanted to change the code to run in column N I would chang 9 to 14 and edit all the terms with I in them to N?  I am trying to run it and it keeps giving me a type mismatch error

Comment: In the above code, there is only 1 place where you'll have to replace 9 with 14. The code **assumes** that the column 9 contains date

Comment: does the firstRow and LastRow columns mean the rows I want the code to run on?

Comment: Precisely. The name of the variable has `rows` in its name.

Comment: AWESOME!!! Got it to work you are amazing... One more question though, I have another date in another column (D) and I want to add into the code to delete the row if the date in column D has allready past?

Comment: Allso How do I make it so that the formating in Row N statys because the cells in that column are supposed to be highlighted if the value is with in 90 days

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for with an image?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have XL on me at the moment, so there may be some syntax errors, but this should be a lot easier on you and very simple to understand and update. Notice I just built the core of the code, I left all your `Application` level stuff out.

```
With Sheets("Copy")

    '.Select -> no need to select anything, you can work right with the object
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Dim myCol as Integer
    myCol = 9

    'the below assumes your data sets starts in column A and you want to filter on column I
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter myCol, xlLast90Days 'this "xlLast90Days" is most likely not right, but if you do it manually while recording a macro, you will get the correct syntax

     Dim rngDelete as Range
     On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no visible cells
     Set rngDelete = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Columns(myCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'assumes first row of usedrange is header row

     'if there are values over 90 delete them
     If not rngDelete is Nothing Then rngDelete.EntireRow.Delete

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are going to want to do is change your For Next loop into a For Each loop.  That way you can just pull every element out of the array and modify it, then put it back.  Like so:

```
'Psuedo code for learing, won't work if used.
Dim gRange as Range 'Generic
Dim testRange as Range

Set testRange = Worksheets("This").Range("Test Column")

For Each gRange in testRange
    If(moreThan90Days)
        gRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next gRange
```

If you need more instruction a quick google search on For Next loops will probably turn up what you're looking for.