# VBA: Add 1 hour to time value in cell

Tags: vba

I have, down one column some times values, e.g. 12:20:00 . I would like to add 1 hour to this value in VBA, so the result would be 13:20:00. 
I have not attempted to write any code for this as not sure where to begin. 
Currently the time value is in M3:M69. All the values, I have to add exactly 1 hour.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938993/run-equation-in-every-cell-in-a-column

Answer (score 1):

A `For Each` loop is used to to loop through all the cells in a `Range`.

```
Sub AddOneHour()

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.Range("M3:M69").Cells
        rCell.Value = rCell.Value + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

First, define a `Range` variable - that will be your control variable in the `For Each` loop. Then you define what range to iterate over - in your case we use the A1-notated address in the `Sheet.Range` property.

Inside the loop, your `Range` variable will point to each successive cell and you can act on that cell's properties. In this case, you change the cells' Value property.

`Timeserial` returns a time given and hour, minute, and second.

Comment: sorry - I forgot to comment and say thank you for your assistance. 
That worked for me FYI